# react dynamically build href file URL using map() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, href

I'm trying to concatenate 2 strings in order to create the href file URL.  One of the string values comes from my DataDocuments array of objects (within the documents.json file).

documents.json file:

```
[   
{ "year":"2017", "ref": "20170303", "file_name": "deed_20170303.pdf", "full_path": "../../../data/statements/deed_20170303.pdf" }, 
{ "year":"2016", "ref": "201604", "file_name": "deed_20160413.pdf", "full_path": "../../../data/statements/deed_20160413.pdf" }  
]
```

I have the following in my code in my attempt to build the href (ATTEMPT #1 - FAILED):

const statementPath="../../../data/statements/";

```
<Table>
{DataDocuments.map((item, index) => (
<tr key={item.type.concat(item.ref)}>
<td><a href={statementPath.concat(item.file_name)} download>{item.file_name}</a></td>
</tr>
))}
</Table>
```

The following code does work whn I simply have the full string defined under my internal depenedencies (ATTEMPT #2 - WORKS):

```
import deed from "../../../data/statements/deed_20170303.pdf";

<Table>
{DataDocuments.map((item, index) => (
<tr key={item.type.concat(item.ref)}>
<td><a href={deed} download>{item.file_name}</a></td>
</tr>
))}
</Table>
```

I thought the problem was how I built the full path string, so I even tried adding "full_path" to the data object, and it still doesn't work (ATTEMPT #3 - FAILED):

```
<Table>
{DataDocuments.map((item, index) => (
<tr key={item.type.concat(item.ref)}>
<td><a href={item.full_path} download>{item.file_name}</a></td>
</tr>
))}
</Table>
```

For ATTEMPT #1 and ATTEMPT #3, I get the download to work, but when I open the file in Adobe Reader, it says "Adobe Reader could not open 'deed_20170303.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged"

All help is appreciated to figure out how I can dynamically build the href within my map method.  THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: if you say the href to something is the value of an import from a location. you can't expect the location path to work for the href. Meaning.. try and do a `console.log(deed)` after import and look at what its value is. I bet its different than the `full_path`

Comment: You're right.  I see the following deed=[/js/images/Statement_20170303.pdf]   I need to check my webpack.config which I know I cobbled together months ago...   {
    test: /\.(pdf|png|jpg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
    use: ["file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]"]
   },

Comment: Theres your answer right there dude. You are trying to set the href of something to `"../../../data/statements/deed_20170303.pdf"` (which you say doesn't work).... when it seems like you should be setting it to `"/js/images/Statement_20170303.pdf"` (which you say works)

Answer (score 2):

@john-ruddell - thanks for your earlier post.  I tried the inline require, but that didn't work.  Your tip to console.log(deed) helped point me in the right direction.

In my webpack.config.js, I had the following:

```
        {
            test: /\.(pdf|png|jpg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
            use: ["file-loader?name=images/[name].[ext]"]
        }
```

And that's way console.log(deed) printed --> "/js/images/Statement_20170303.pdf"

I modified my webpack.config.js to:

```
  {
    test: /\.(pdf|png|jpg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
    use: ["file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]"]
  },
```

And changed my code to:

```
<a href={"/js/data/statements/".concat(item.file_name)} download>
```

For now as I'm still learning React, this will work.  As I become more familiar with Webpack and React, I hope to find a better way to resolve this.  THANKS!

Comment: awesome crawford! glad I was able to help you figure out your issue. Remember whenever you have an issue and you don't know how it could be wrong, the issue is most likely you are expecting it to be something it is not. Use `console.log` or `debugger` statements to debug and investigate your code. Will be very helpful! :) happy coding!